# Masonry layout on a divi woocommerce wordpress

Tags: wordpress, plugins, woocommerce, masonry

I am trying to add a Masonry layout into shop products using the woocommerce plugin, but there is no way. Actually, I've just seen how to add a Masonry layout on a gallery of pictures, but not on a shop page. I would like to know if there is such a plugin or a way to handle this.